# Efficiently join XML to a collection, and then perform an update to the XML

Tags: c#

Can anyone please help me out with the lambda expression for fetching the value for which i used foreach loop?

```
foreach (var keysValue in configParameters)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (childNode.Attributes["key"].Value == keysValue.Key)
                {
                    childNode.Attributes["value"].Value = keysValue.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Since i have not exposed to lamba expression, i am asking you all. kindly help me out in learning also.

Comment: It's not lambda expression these are foreach loops. Lambda is a delegate function

Comment: @wudzik I think he's looking for an equivalent to simplify the code. Maybe?

Comment: ya equivalent code to simplify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var updateInfos =
 from XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes
 let key = childNode.Attributes["key"].Value
 join keysValue in configParameters on key equals keysValue.Key
 select new { childNode, keysValue.Value };
```

That efficiently joins the two collections. Now we update:

```
foreach (var updateInfo in updateInfos)
 updateInfo.childNode.Attributes["value"].Value = updateInfo.Value;
```

We do as much as possible in the functional LINQ query. Then we update using `foreach`. It is useful to separate queries and mutations as much as possible. Use LINQ for the query part, use `foreach` for mutations.